# Rails validations with enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an enum in my Box model

```
enum box_type: [:wooden, :plastic, :metal, :paper]
```

and I want the `box_type` attribute of my Box model to be only one of those, so:

```
validates :box_type, inclusion: {in: box_types.keys }
```

It seems that it should be working flawlessly, but what I also have is a default value when creating my Box model, set like this:

```
class CreateBoxes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :boxes do |t|
        ...
        t.string  :box_type,      null: false, default: "paper"
        ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and when I try to create a record in my console I get a rollback. 
Error:

```
@messages={:box_type=>["is not included in the list"]}, @details={:box_type=>[{:error=>:inclusion, :value=>nil}]}
```

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there any better way to only allow particular values inside my database column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` stores integer in database, not string. Try changing the column type to integer and default to 0

> Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the
>   database, but can be queried by name.